# Error getting result from second query using variables from first query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I get result from first query correctly However, when I want to use them in second query in WHERE condition I get query error 1064. If I remove WHERE it will work fine. Also,when I try to echo variables inside while in second query code it will print.the variables will not work only in WHERE in second query

```html
 $queryDate = "SELECT date , time from DATES where ID = $ID";
 $result = mysqli_query($connection, $queryDate);
 
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  
   $date = $row['date']; 
   $time = $row['time'];

   } 
 }
 
 $queryCom = "SELECT * from DATES, BOOKING where dates.time = $time and booking.IDofFullDate= $date";
 $result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $queryCom);
 if (!$result1)
    {
 
     die("Query Faile".  mysqli_errno($connection));   
    }
 
 if ($result1->num_rows >0) {
     echo $date;
     echo $time;
 }
```

Comment: The full error message usually indicates exactly where the problem is... but you should use parameterized queries; your issue is most likely because the variables you are using in the query need delimited by `'`

Comment: What is the point of the while loop in this script? You are only ever going to run the second query on the last set of dates and times

Comment: thank Uueerdo it works now. some time the issue will be crazy

Comment: You are getting a syntax error.  MySQL is generally case sensitive.  If your tables (DATES and BOOKING) are in upper case, then they should be upper case in the  WHERE statement.   Also, you should use some type of JOIN statement.

Answer (score 0):

on your second query try this below:

```
$queryCom = "SELECT * from DATES as dates, BOOKING as booking where dates.time = $time and booking.IDofFullDate= $date";
```